# Managing iOS devices from wso2 emm console

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I have setup WSO 2 emm 2.0.1 in development environment. I was able to successfully enroll android device and check the MDM policies of android device. I did not do any additional platform configuration by creating any kind of certificate to get android emm working. But in case of IOS wso2 profile is not getting installed. And while installing iOS agent error is can not connect *serverIP*. Do I need to create all the certificate as mentioned in the link https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM201/iOS+Platform+Configurations . I have never worked with android and iOS devices previously .

Please help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to follow all the instructions provided in the following documentation in order to enable communication with your ios devices.
These are protocols provided by Apple to ensure the device security.

- https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM201/iOS+Platform+Configurations
- https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM201/Generating+a+MDM+APNS+Certificate

Make sure to complete all the configurations where you need to put your ip or domain as provided in the [documentations](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM201/Configuring+the+Product)

Obtaining a signed CSR from wso2 also required in order to use emm server to manage ios devices.

Refer to the below tutorial if you are using a public server with a SSL certificate obtain from a know Certificate Authority.

- http://kamidupunchihewa.blogspot.com/2016/07/configure-device-communication-when.html